# Aggregating common character values per group in R

Tags: r, dplyr, cpu-word

I have a data frame as follows:

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(Comments = c("This is good", "What is the price", "You are no good", "help the needy", "What a beautiful day", "how can I help you", "You are my best friend", "she is my friend", "which one is the best", "How can she do that"
), ID = c("A1", "B2", "A1", "C3", "D4", "C3", "E5", "E5", "E5", 
"E5")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 10L))
```

Based off unique ID, I want to get all common character values within each group.

From suggestions, I tried the following codes

```
check <-  aggregate(Comments ~ ID, demo, function(x){
   temp = table(unlist(lapply(strsplit(x, ","), unique)))
   temp = names(temp)[which(temp == max(temp) & temp > 1)]
   if (length(temp) == 0) temp = ""
   temp
 })
```

This gives unique IDs but shows empty rows for common words

```
demo %>% 
  mutate(Words = strsplit(Comments, " ")) %>% 
  unnest %>% 
  intersect(Comments) %>% 
  group_by(ID, Comments) %>% 
  summarise(Words = toString(Comments))
```

This gives me error.

My expected output is :

```
ID  Comments
A1  "good"
B2  ""
C3  "help"
D4  ""
E5  "best, friend, she, is, my"
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I think in `E5`, `is` and `my` would also be there

Comment: If you have a typo, then `data %>% separate_rows(Comments) %>% count(Comments, ID) %>%filter(n == max(n)) %>% select(-n) %>% complete(ID = unique(data$ID), fill = list(Comments = "")) %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(Comments = toString(Comments))`

Comment: Yes, you are right even `is` and `my` are also included. Thanks for the catch. I tried the code, it gives me error `Error in count(., Comments, ID) : object 'Comments' not found`. `Comments` is in my dataframe, I dont understand why I am getting this error.  Can you explain the code please? thank you @akrun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, we can create a column with `row_number()` to get the common words in each `ID`. We use `tidyr::separate_rows` to separate words into different rows, `filter` only those `Comments` which occur in more than 1 row, `group_by` `ID` and create a comma-separated string.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(row = row_number(), 
         ID = factor(ID)) %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(Comments, sep = "\\s+") %>%
  group_by(ID, Comments) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(row) > 1) %>%
  group_by(ID, .drop = FALSE) %>% 
  summarise(Comments = toString(unique(Comments)))



#  ID    Comments                 
#  <fct> <chr>                    
#1 A1    good                     
#2 B2    ""                       
#3 C3    help                     
#4 D4    ""                       
#5 E5    my, best, friend, she, is
```

Comment: How do you get `my, best, friend, she, is` for E5 from:
`7  You are my best friend E5
8        she is my friend E5
9   which one is the best E5
10    How can she do that E5`. I am trying to understand what OP wants here. I thought nothing is common in E5 as we have to take common words from all rows of the same group.

Comment: @MAPK I initially thought the same that OP wants common from all the rows in each group. However, they actually want a word which is present in atleast 2 rows in each. Therefore, `my, best, friend, she, is` from `E5`.

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr`, we can do

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
     separate_rows(Comments) %>% 
      count(Comments, ID) %>%
      filter(n == max(n)) %>%
      select(-n) %>%
      complete(ID = unique(data$ID), fill = list(Comments = "")) %>% 
      group_by(ID) %>% 
      summarise(Comments = toString(Comments))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  ID    Comments                 
#  <chr> <chr>                    
#1 A1    good                     
#2 B2    ""                       
#3 C3    help                     
#4 D4    ""                       
#5 E5    best, friend, is, my, she
```